# Can't access function in index.js (webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack

Why can't I access a function in my Javascript file?  It's like it doesn't exist.

I created a simple webpack project

```
npm init
npm i -D webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-env
```

I set up my `package.json` with build scripts and create my `webpack.config.js` file.

I create my `index.js` file and inside I define a function:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log('test');
}
```

I create an `index.html` file, link it to my `bundle.js` that is being output from webpack.

I create a simple link on the index.html file with `onclick="myFunction()"`

When I click the link it tells me my function is not defined.  What gives?

Comment: JS modules do not create global variables.  You should put all of your code in Webpack files only.

Comment: Put my code in Webpack files?  What does that mean?  My function is defined in `index.js` which is the `entry` file for Webpack.  It should be accessible, no?

Comment: No; it only exists in the scope of the module.  Learn about how JS modules work,

Comment: How do I write a function in the index.js and have it accessible from the onclick?

Comment: Don't use onclick.  Instead, add your handlers from JS.

Comment: Okay, I can do that.  I still don't understand why my function isn't accessible but I'll take some time to refresh on my JS and hopefully figure it out.

Comment: The point of modules is to stop leaking global variables (so you don't need to worry about collisions).  Therefore, they don't expose their contents except via `export`.

Comment: I tried exporting it and that didn't work.  I think I need to refresh on JS modules.

Comment: `exports` still don't create globals (again to avoid collisions); they just allow `import`.

Comment: My mistake.  I was thinking everything other than modules being imported into `index.js` would be global.  By making it global with `window.myFunction = function() {}` everything is working.

Comment: been bangin my head for hours, thanks for "window.something" so i can access my var and function globally. I think i really need to learn the whole module concept lol

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a function inside **index.js** and try to access that in **index.html** file on a input Keypress. And got error.

**Solution:**
In my case I defined the function with window object and this resolve my issue. For instance

The function is inside index.js and then in index.html file access it on keypress like this as given below

```js
window.isNumberKey = function(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    console.log(false);
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log(true);
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
```